# Too many redirects. How to redirect to a another level

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have in the .htaccess on this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule 41-advent /escrits/41-advent [L,R=301]
```

If I go to myDomain/41-advent

Safari says: "Too many redirects occurred trying to open myDomain/41-advent. This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which then is redirected to open the original page."

Chrome says: myDomain.org redirected too many times

I insist that I deleted all the other code in .htaccess. I only have the two lines above.

What is the right way to redirect?:
from myDomain.com/41-advent
to:  myDomain.com/escrits/41-advent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your regex will cause redirect loop since you're not using anchors.

Use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^41-advent/?$ /escrits/41-advent [L,R=301,NC]
```

Now it will match `myDomain.com/41-advent` but not `myDomain.com/escrits/41-advent`

Comment: I understand, very good answer. Just a doubt: if the search does not begin with the "/", why the substitution must begin with that "/" ?

Comment: Yes that's the thing with .htaccess. `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. I am a beginner. Can you try again, please

Comment: htaccess can be placed in any sub-directory under `DocumentRoot`. While using `RewriteRule` it matches path relative from that directory. So if htaccess is in DocumentRoot i.e. `/` then it starts matching after first `/`